# How many ways do I have to sort the parenthesis in the sum of n terms, such that we have in each parenthesis the sum of only two terms.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways do I have to sort the parenthesis in the sum of n terms, such that we have in each parenthesis the sum of only two terms. E.G.:

For $n=3$ there are $2$ ways:

- $((a+b)+c)$
- $(a+(b+c))$

For $n=4$ there are $5$ ways:

- $(((a+b)+c)+d)$
- $((a+(b+c))+d)$
- $(a+((b+c)+d))$
- $(a+(b+(c+d)))$
- $((a+b)+(c+d))$

Comment: You should post at least one more example (of $n=5$), for the other readers as well as for yourself - in order to help us (and you) to identify the pattern.

Comment: Look up [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).